# How can I set the Binding Order in a DataTemplate for Command and CommandParameter

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, command, datatemplate

I am looking for the correct way to specify the bindings for a DataTemplate.

For the correct initialisation of a Command it is relevant in what order CommandParamter and Commands bindings happen.

Here is a xaml and some sourcecode to illustrate the point.
The example contains 4 Commands, 2 are expected to not initialize correctly. 2 are supposed to initialize correctly.
The two trivial cases behave as expected.
The two DataTemplate cases do not behave as I expect.

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFCommand.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFCommand"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button 
            Command="{Binding CMD1}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Parameter1}"
            >CMD->PAR</Button>
        <Button 
            CommandParameter="{Binding Parameter2}"
            Command="{Binding CMD2}"
            >PAR->CMD</Button>
        <DataGrid
            ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridItemsSource}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            HeadersVisibility="None"
            >
            <DataGrid.Columns >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="1*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button
                                Command="{Binding CMD4}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Parameter4}"
                                >Grid CMD->PAR</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="1*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Parameter3}"
                                Command="{Binding CMD3}"
                                >Grid PAR->CMD</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Codebehind

```
namespace WPFCommand
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Input;

    public class DemoCommand : ICommand
    {
        bool? oldCanEx;
        private string myname;

        public DemoCommand(string myname)
        {
            this.myname = myname;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            bool newCanEx;
            if (parameter == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{myname} CanExecute called with null");
                newCanEx = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{myname} CanExecute called with {parameter}");
                newCanEx = true;
            }

            if (oldCanEx != newCanEx)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{myname} CanExecute changed");
                oldCanEx = newCanEx;
                CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            return newCanEx;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{myname} Execute {parameter}");
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        internal Item() { }
        public DemoCommand CMD3 { get; private set; } = new DemoCommand("CMD3");
        public DemoCommand CMD4 { get; private set; } = new DemoCommand("CMD4");
        public int Parameter3 { get; private set; } = 7;
        public int Parameter4 { get; private set; } = 13;
    }

    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Item> DataGridItemsSource { get; private set; } = new List<Item> { new Item() };
        public DemoCommand CMD1 { get; private set; } = new DemoCommand("CMD1");
        public DemoCommand CMD2 { get; private set; } = new DemoCommand("CMD2");
        public int Parameter1 { get; private set; } = 42;
        public int Parameter2 { get; private set; } = 5;
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

CMD1 and CMD2 are outside of the DataTemplate. CMD3 and CMD4 are Inside.
Both show the same difference in the ordering of the bindings.

Here is the Debug output:

```
CMD1 CanExecute called with null
CMD1 CanExecute changed
CMD1 CanExecute called with null
CMD2 CanExecute called with 5
CMD2 CanExecute changed
CMD2 CanExecute called with 5
CMD4 CanExecute called with null
CMD4 CanExecute changed
CMD4 CanExecute called with null
CMD3 CanExecute called with null
CMD3 CanExecute changed
CMD3 CanExecute called with null
```

CMD1 Fails to initialize corretly as expected.
CMD2 Succeeds as expected.
CMD4 Fails as expeted.
CMD3 Fails and I did not expect that.

Why did the parameter of CMD3 not bind before the Command?

What is the correct way to write the xaml for a DataTemplated Command/CommandParameter binding (ideally without touching the code behind)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Issue can be resolved by putting the DataTemplate Contents into their own view.

Use

```
<DataTemplate>
    <local:CommandView />
</DataTemplate>
```

With CommandView beeing a custom UserControl.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFCommand.CommandView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFCommand"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Button
        CommandParameter="{Binding Parameter3}"
        Command="{Binding CMD3}"
        >Grid PAR->CMD</Button>
</UserControl>
```